# How can I see that it is indeed a foreign key and the parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have created a table which has a foreign key as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE interests  
(
    int_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    an_interest VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
    contact_id INT NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk  
    FOREIGN KEY (contact_id)  
    REFERENCES my_contacts (contact_id)  
);
```

When I do `DESC` I see:

```
mysql> desc interests;  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| int_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| interest   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| contact_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I know what `MUL` is but how would I explicitely see that `contact_id` is defined as a foreign key and which is the parent table via CLI?
Also why can't I use `my_contacts_contact_id_fk` to drop the foreign key constraint?

**UPDATE**

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE interests DROP CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk;  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear 'CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk' at line 2
mysql>
```

Comment: your table name is interests or my_interests ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari:Sorry.Copy-paste problem.Fixed OP

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE interests;`

Comment: @Travesty3:Only by viewing the original `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), I think the syntax for dropping the constraint would be `ALTER TABLE interests DROP FOREIGN KEY my_contacts_contact_id_fk;`. And if you can verify that the foreign key exists by viewing the original `CREATE TABLE` statement, why do you need another way to verify it?

Comment: @Travesty3:I was just wondering if I should be able to see this info from the description of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are database objects in themselves so it doesn't surprise me that the full description of the constraint is not shown when you run 
`desc [interests]`.
Try `desc [my_contacts_contact_id_fk]`?

You should be able to execute `alter table [interests] drop constraint [my_contacts_contact_id_fk]`. If you are having trouble dropping can you post your alter table SQL and the response from the server?

Comment: The syntax 
    `ALTER TABLE interests DROP CONSTRAINT my_contacts_contact_id_fk;` 
seems valid to me. Try qualifying the table name and constraint 
name with back ticks (like square brackets in MSSQL Server):
`ALTER TABLE \`interests\` DROP CONSTRAINT \`my_contacts_contact_id_fk\`; `

Comment: Note you can also query the information_schema tables to check the FK exists:
`select * from information_schema.check_constraints` &  `information_schema.constraint_column_usage` I believe.  
Edit: It seems mysql's info schema tables are named slightly different to the ones I quoted (from mssql). This link describes them:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html